# Get multistate buttons for Dreamweaver CS5?

Tags: dreamweaver

I'm trying to design some buttons with a rollover behavior: changing either color or shape or both based upon hover status. My artistic skills are between zero and nil. Can you recommend a "roll your own" button designer?